# How to send header in flask send_file?

Tags: python, flask, header, sendfile

**The problem** is I am unable to send headers when using `send_file`, is there any workaround for this?

**I want to**  be able to send headers when sending files to client.

```
return send_file(mp3_filepath, 'audio/mpeg')
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
from flask import make_response, send_file    

response = make_response(send_file(mp3_filepath))
response.headers['X-Something'] = 'header value goes here'
return response
```